# Restrict multiple user login to web application from same machine when one user is logged on, in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, web

I have to restrict new user from logging to my web application at the same time one user is loggged on from that system, when both users are using same machine. (ie if one user is logged in then if another user tries from the same machine, i should restrict that second user to login in that same machine)

I think about mac id validation but its not possible to get in c# (cant use active-x javascript to get id).Is this possible to track using cookies..

Can anyone suggest some solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Use windows authentication and maintain the session of user and check the same on log in!!

OR

Forms Authentication with cookies (regardless of whether they are persistent or not) is browser session based (persistent cookie would of course work across multiple sessions of same browser (on same user account on same machine). So two browser sessions (or two different browsers or browser on two machines etc) would be treated as different scope as far forms authentication is concerned.

So user can make multiple login from different browser sessions and logout in one will not affect other. Its is up to web application whether to allow multiple concurrent logins for same user or not. For example, online banking sites would restrict to only one user session - so if user logs in from different session then earlier session is invalidated (i.e. user is logged out). One has to write custom implementation in ASP.NET to do so - typical implementation would make every user session entry into database (typically required for audit purposes anyway) - so whenever new entry is added, a check is made to see if there is any active session for same user and if yes then that session is marked inactive. Every request would check if current user session is active or not, if not then it would flag such message to user.

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of above scenario can be varied as per requirement. I would do this using saving `user session` in my database along with the `IP address`. Now whenever a new request would come, I will check whether is there any active session on this machine is present or not. If yes then I would not allow the new user to logged in.

You can also save this information in cookie, but If user delete the cookie, he would be allow to logged in.

Comment: but how would you access `Machine Id` of client PC in asp web site ??

Comment: yss how to get machine ID of client PC..?

Comment: ohhk, will look into this, untill You can use the ipAddress as well for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

**global.asax Source Code**

```
 private int mnSessionMinutes = 2;
 private string msSessionCacheName="SessionTimeOut";

public void InsertSessionCacheItem(string sUserID)
{

   try
     {
         if (this.GetSessionCacheItem(sUserID) != "") { return; }
         CacheItemRemovedCallback oRemove = new CacheItemRemovedCallback(this.SessionEnded);
         System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(msSessionCacheName + sUserID,sUserID,null, DateTime.MaxValue, 

TimeSpan.FromMinutes(mnSessionMinutes),CacheItemPriority.High,oRemove);
      }
      catch (Exception e) { Response.Write(e.Message); }
}

public string GetSessionCacheItem(string sUserID)
{
      string sRet="";

      try
       {
         sRet = (string)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache[msSessionCacheName + sUserID];
         if (sRet == null) { sRet = ""; }
        }
       catch (Exception) { }
       return sRet;
}


public void SessionEnded(string key, object val, CacheItemRemovedReason r)
{

    string sUserID="";
    string sSessionTest="";

   try
    {
      sSessionTest = Session["Test"].ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception e) { sSessionTest = e.Message;}

    try
    {

        sUserID = (string)val;
     // Make sure your SMTP service has started in order for this to work

        System.Web.Mail.MailMessage message = new System.Web.Mail.MailMessage();

        message.Body = "your session has ended for user : " + sUserID + " - Session String: " + sSessionTest;
        message.To = "your email goes here";
        message.From = "info@eggheadcafe.com";
        message.BodyFormat = System.Web.Mail.MailFormat.Text;
        message.Subject = "Session On End";

        System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(message);     

        message = null;

     }
     catch (Exception) { }

}
```

**default.aspx Source Code**

```
<script Language="C#" runat="server">

 protected string msUserID = "201";
 protected string msSessionCacheValue="";

 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) { ProcessPage(); }

 public void ProcessPage()
 {
    Session["Test"] = "test string to see if session variables still exist after app recycle.";

    ((global_asax)Context.ApplicationInstance).InsertSessionCacheItem(msUserID);

   // Test to access the cache and make sure it still exists
    msSessionCacheValue = ((global_asax)Context.ApplicationInstance).GetSessionCacheItem(msUserID);
 }

</script>   

<HTML><BODY>

 <table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" width="70%">
  <tr><td><br></td></tr>
  <tr><td><br></td></tr>
  <tr><td align="left">Close the browser and wait for email notification</td></tr>
  <tr><td><br></td></tr>
  <tr><td align="left"><a href=default.aspx target=_self>Redirect to this page to reaccess the cache</a></td></tr>
  <tr><td><br></td></tr>
  <tr><td align="left"><%=  Session["Test"].ToString()  %></td></tr>
  <tr><td><br></td></tr>
  <tr><td align="left"><%= msSessionCacheValue %></td></tr>
 </table>

</body></html>
```

I think you might be able to do this using cache. you have not given specific scenario so i would not be give specific answer. but you can look at following tutorials.

[Preventing Multiple Logins in ASP.NET](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20030416.asp)

[Prevent Multiple Logins Using the Cache in ASP.NET](http://www.nullskull.com/articles/20030416.asp)

Comment: I have one user USERA logged to the system in a machine, if another user USERB comes and tries to login to the system in same machine.. then i have to inform USERA is using this system and you cannot access this system.

Answer (score 0):

If user is using different browsers then i don't think it possible but for same browser if you are facing this problem then you may have missed checking user session/cookie whatever you use for logged in user on login page.

e.g. on login.aspx page if i get my cookie/session null that means user has logged out. Else i should redirect the user to page after login (Do not allow user to stay on login.aspx when user is already logged in)